# Why is my website shows abnormally low CTR in Google Search Console?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

The problem is my website has abnormally low CTR in all query words including "my own website name" keyword but let me explain using only when people search my website name as an example.

**The evidence of abnormally low CTR, what's happening here ?**

Assume that my website name is "abcfoobar" with domain name "abcfoobar.com" and I confirm that my site name does not exist anywhere in any dictionary.

When people search "abcfoobar", my site always shows at the first position on google. However, the search console performance shows abnormally low CTR as shown the picture where the correlation between total impression and clicks are totally impossible.

**Based on the images below**

1. the keyword blocked by green pen is the main keyword of my site positioning 3.4, but only 3 clicks out of 971 impressions.
2. the keyword blocked by bluepen is "abcfoobar", my website name, positioning at first, but only 5% click which is impossible because the only reason that people will type this keyword is to find my website, similar to why people type "facebook" in google.
3. "abcfoobar.com" received only 1/9 CTR which is impossible because the only reason that people will type this keyword is to find my website.

[image: Google Search Performance Result]

[image]

**Question**

I wonder what are the reasons behind this abnormally low CTR results. My website has 3,000 unique users daily and I'm sure people click more than as of shown in the result. As a newbie here, now I'm not sure if I understand CTR correctly.

Comment: What does analytics say about entrances by source/medium? By your comment to the suggested answer, I think it might be possible that people write the name of the site in the navigation bar (the url bar in every browser) and it autocompletes, therefore there is no high search volume and no high CTR...

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if you add som FAQ schema and people only read them ? Maybe a bad review display in the SERP so people don't click. According to the overall stats, you website got traffic but on words different than brands, seems the brand is not powerfull enough in a marketing way.

it could also be the ranking monitoring system you or someone else is using: it generate displays but no click.

Comment: Blaming the ranking monitoring system is also my assumption. This website is well-known in Thailand. Im totally sure it's clicked more than a thousand, users traverse in my site 40,000 pages/day, and no popup or anything blocking from access via google. Perhaps  I need to contact Google for this case now. Anyway, just for more info, the site frontend uses Next.js. No idea if there is something with server rendering.